# Two different versions of the same base theme in the same site

Tags: theming

I'm wondering if it's possible to get two different branches of the same theme into the same site, both to be used as base themes.

Specifically I'm talking about Omega 7.x-3 and Omega 7.x-4 in the same site, but I guess the question applies to any theme.

Rationale: We're using Omega 4.x for the main theme (because of the nice front end stack), but for commerce sites (which this is), we also like to include [Omega Kickstart](https://drupal.org/project/omega_kickstart) as the admin theme. It's an improvement over Seven for very little work and clients seem to like it.

However, Omega Kickstart uses Omega 3.x as its base theme, and so conflicts with the newer version that's installed.

Short of taking a copy of one of the Omega versions, renaming it and all its internal functions, and then building a sub-theme from *that*, is there any way to get this sort of workflow?

**UPDATE**

Ok, er, so I made a bit of a mistake. I actually want to use the Shiny theme, not Omega Kickstart. Whoops.

But let's say I didn't, and definitely wanted to use Omega 3.x and 4.x in the same site...how might that go?

Comment: if you really cover every renaming of the machine name omega_ to omega3_ etc. this should work out just as usual. Though I am not aware of asset files, such as js libraries, that might lead to conflicts.

Comment: Rather than go through all that, why not just use the [Shiny Admin](https://drupal.org/project/shiny) theme, which I think the Kickstart Omega Admin theme is based on?

Comment: Arrgh I feel like an idiot, Shiny was actually what I'm talking about! I got confused between that and Omega Kickstart. I think it's still an interesting general question so I'll edit it and make it more generic - thank you very much for the sanity check

Comment: @Serpiente Yeah I'm pretty sure that should work in theory, I was wondering if there's any other way round that didn't involve renaming all of alpha and omega's internal functions

Comment: a workaround could also be modifying the system registry for specific requests. (I post this in comments because this sounds wrong and ugly while I am writing it): https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7 that would probably only cover the implements callbacks and might not take care of lazy loading all of the information in .info and attaching assets as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes, like modules, are identified by their names. The version number is never really used (except for updates obviously).

Anyway, i found myself facing a similar problem sometimes, and running a find&replace on the theme directory to change every occurrence of the name with another inside the files never lead to unexpected behaviors.

well, i also had to manually rename the .info file, so it's not a completely automatic procedure, but still nothing that caused problems of any sort.